# Command that launches a graphical text input box that outputs to stdout

Tags: shell

Is there such a program that can open a little input box and send the input to stdout? If there isn't, any suggestions for how to do this (maybe python with TkInter)?

Comment: You forgot your operating system. This is pretty important information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for something that works in text mode, then [`dialog`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) or [`whiptail`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/whiptail) are two options.

Answer (score 0):

The oldest would probably be [dialog](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2807). Another example of such a program is [Zenity](http://freshmeat.net/projects/zenity) and another would be [Xdialog](http://xdialog.free.fr/) (all pretty much replacements for dialog).

They tend to do more than just accepting user input, and you can create some fairly complex GUI dialogs with them, but are simple enough to do what you want very easily.